# Modified Hat-Check Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a following problem: $k$ friends walk into a bar and give their hats to a wardrobe, but then hats get mixed-up together with other hats in the wardrobe. There is $p$ hats in the wardrobe, $p \geq k$. What is the probability that exactly $i$ number of friends, $i \leq k$, get their hats back? If $p=k$, this is the standard partial derangement problem, but if $p \geq k$, then things are a bit more complicated, and I could not figure out a solution.

Comment: Is the answer ${^p C _i}\frac{(p-i)!}{p!}$ ? I am not at all sure about it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the solution to the derangement problem via inclusion exclusion? The same method works here. First, choose the set $S$ of people who get their hat back, $|S|=i$. Then assign the other hats arbitrarily, subtract the ways where some person not in $S$ get their hat, add back in the ways where two people not in $S$ got their hat back, etc.

Comment: I finally figured it out 2 days ago. I thought inclusion-exclusion principle should work here, but struggled to derive the general formula for an arbitrary $k$.